# Retrieve IP from a mail I received

Tags: networking, email, security, ip

I already made some researches about this subject on the interwab, but I couldn't find what I wanted.

Here is the point.

I'm a beginner highly interested onto web security and something blew my mind.

I had a mail from someone (so I know that this is a living person) and I tried to get his IP address.

I found some useless IP like his server (google) and some other, but, some of them were interesting.

They were part of the 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 range

So far, the trackers I used either show me the ocean, or told me that they were untraceable.

Could someone light my head up on this ? 
What are those IP address, and why can't I track them down ?

Here is the source code I extracted from the mailing page :

```
Return-Path: herEmailAddress@gmail.com //adress and IP voluntary hidden.
Received: from 10.xxx.xx.xx (LHLO lpn-prd-vrin019) (10.xx.xx.xx) by
 lpn-prd-mstr050 with LMTP; Wed, 19 Aug 2015 00:36:01 +0200 (CEST)
```

This is the very first time I'm seeing this kind of thing..

Thanks for your consideration!

Comment: `10.xxx.xx.xx` is a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) so you cannot locate it.

Comment: If someone sends email using mail.google.com you cannot find their location.

Comment: But, why does Google hides their IP address while other email providing services does not ?

Comment: I guess for sender's privacy

Comment: send them an email (perhaps from a different account) with a link to a website that you control. If they click the link, you can get their (router's) IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Received` headers in an email only track the mail servers that an email passes through.  Mail servers run software like `sendmail`, `exim`, `qmail`, `postfix`, and such.

When a user access gmail, he is accessing a web site, not a mail server. The gmail web site runs some kind of mail server software and sends email.  The gmail mail server becomes the first (or last, depending on how you look at it) server in the email chain.

10.X.X.X IP addresses are reserved by RFC1918 for internal use.  Anybody can use those IP addresses, as long as they are kept internal and network-address-translated to a public IP address before traversing the Internet.